# Find to Near by Geo location using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

geoNear: function (lat, lon) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      UserLocation.geoNear({type: 'Point', coordinates: [parseFloat(query.lat), parseFloat(query.lon)]},
        {distanceField: 'dist.calculated', maxDistance: 100, spherical: true}, function (error, data) {
        console.log('Error', error);
          resolve((error) ? {} : (data == null) ? {} : data)
      })
    })
  },

Comment: I want to fine Ner by Geo Location with Latitude and Longitude in NodeJS & Monggose

Comment: The question is not clear. Please add more information and format the question accordingly.

Comment: How can i get Near by Geo Location Latitude and Longitude in NodeJS & Mongodb.
which action query I have to write?

Answer (score 0):

Let the document like

```
{
"_id" : 3,
"name" : "Polo Grounds",
"location": {
  "type" : "Point",
  "coordinates" : [ -73.9375, 40.8303 ]
}
}
```

You can query using

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.98142 , 40.71782 ] },
    key: "location",
    distanceField: "dist.calculated"
 }
}
])
```

For more details [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)